# how to display python time.time() stored as a float in bigquery as a datetime?

Tags: python, time, google-bigquery

I am a bigquery newbie

we have a table that stores the output from time.time() as float. For example

```
1671057937.23425
1670884516.891432
```

How can I select these values such that they are formated/displayed as date and time stamp.

I have tried casting to int64, using various date/time functions like DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE and TIMESTAMP_MICROS

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the time() function returns the number of seconds passed since epoch - so you can use below simple approach

```
select timestamp_micros(cast(1670884516.891432 * 1000000 as int64))
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert back to readable date time with python:

```
import datetime

stamp = "1670884516.891432"
readable = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(stamp))
print(readable)
```

result:

```
2022-12-13 01:35:16.891432
```

Please, formulate the question more clearly.

What do you mean with your words:

> How can I select these values ...

Do you mean to select with SQL query? Then

```
SELECT convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,21) ;
```